# Vuejs D3 V7 Zoom in Zoom Out in Radial Tree

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

Hello Everyone I'm struggling for a while with what i thought was a peace of Cake, but not.

- I'have a Vuejs (v2) component  that render a D3 (v7.8.5). radial Tree (full project is build with electron).
  The rendering is fine
  [image]
- I have a @wheel on the div that contains the SVG rendering
- The wheel trigger a method that check if ctrl key is down (zoom in zoom out only when ctrl+ wheel)
- If wheel Delta <0 Do ZoomIn
- If wheel Delta >0 Do ZoomOut

My code so far looks like

Template

```
...
<v-row class ="ma-4 d-flex justify-center" v-if="Mainview">
       <div ref="chartContainer" class="chart-container" @wheel="HandleChartZoom"></div>
</v-row>
...
```

Script

```
...
mounted(){
this.drawChart(this.graphData)

},

methods:{
drawChart(datapayload) {
            d3.select("svg").remove()
            const data = datapayload 

            const width = 1500;
            const height = 900;
            const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.6;

            const svg = d3
                .select(this.$refs.chartContainer)
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`)      

            const treeLayout = d3.tree().size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

            const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
            const treeData = treeLayout(root);

            // eslint-disable-next-line
            const link = svg
                .selectAll('.link')
                .data(treeData.links())
                .enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('class', 'link')
                .attr('d', d3.linkRadial().angle(d => d.x).radius(d => d.y))
                .attr('stroke-width', '2px')
                .attr('stroke', d => d.source.data.color)
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                          
            const node = svg
                .selectAll('.node')
                .data(treeData.descendants())
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node')                
                .attr(
                'transform',
                d => `rotate(${(d.x * 180) / Math.PI - 90}) translate(${d.y}, 0)`
                )
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                .on('mouseover', function(d){

                    d3.select(this).select('text').attr("font-size", "1.5em").attr("font-weight", "bold");
                })
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                .on('mouseout',function(d){

                    d3.select(this).select('text').attr("font-size", "0.65em").attr("font-weight", "normal");
                })
                .on("contextmenu",d => this.handleNodeRightClick(d));

                

            node
                .append('circle')
                .attr('r', 4)
                .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.data.color; })
                

            node
                .append('text')
                .attr('dy', '0.31em')
                .attr("font-size", "0.65em")
                .attr('x', d => (d.x < Math.PI ? 6 : -6))
                .attr('text-anchor', d => (d.x < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end'))
                .attr('transform', d => (d.x >= Math.PI ? 'rotate(180)' : null))
                .text(d => d.data.name)
                .attr('id',function(d) { return d.data.Id; })
                // .on('click',d => this.handleNodeClick(d))
                
                
        },
 HandleChartZoom(e){
        if(!e.ctrlKey){return}
        const Xpos= e.offsetX
        const Ypos=e.offsetY
            if(e.deltaY<0){
                console.log("zoomIn")
                // do ZoomIn 10 % center on Xpos Ypos
            }
            if(e.deltaY>0){
                console.log("zoomOut")
                // do ZoomOut 10% center on mouse position Xpos Ypos
            }
        }
}


...
```

I tried several Way to Achieve ZoomIn ZoomOut
Like

- [How to set up d3-zoom correctly in vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66900901/how-to-set-up-d3-zoom-correctly-in-vue)
- https://www.d3indepth.com/zoom-and-pan/
- https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/d3-zoom/functions/d3-zoom.zoom
- https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_zoom.html

But nothing worked in my case
Thanks for the help